# How to translate a lambda expression into English?

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I'm a VB.NET programmer who also knows some C#. I've recently come across lambda expressions which [in VB can look like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

```
a = Function() b + c
```

However [in C# they look like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
a => b + c;
```

(Which, to me, looks a lot like a bizarre pointer expression from C)

The problem is that when reading C# code I mentally parse the operators into english words. So `a = b + c;` becomes "add b and c and assign to a". However I have no mental translation in my built in parser for the for the `=>` operator yet so `a => b + c;` becomes either "a equals pointer to b and c" which makes no sense or "a is a lambda of b and c" which is dreadful.

I'm sure that the language creators meant for that operator to stand for a concept and that concept should be able to be reduced to a single word or very short phrase.

So what is the intended English translation for the `=>` operator?

p.s. Note that I've tried to make the examples to be as simple as possible so as not to get bogged down in the specifics.

Comment: get `a` and return `b + c`? Your lambda is not good example. Let's imagine something like `a => a.ToString()`, it has the meaning "get `a` and return string representation of `a`".

Comment: a is function b + c ?  That way it stays in check with your vb.net experience

Answer (score 7):

You have your example slightly wrong.

This VB code

```
a = Function()
  Return b + c
End Function
```

looks like this in C#:

```
Func<int> a = () => b + c;
```

The problem with the suggestion of calling `=>` "returns" is that this doesn't work with lambdas that don't return anything:

For example:

```
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

If you call `=>` "returns" in that scenario, it would be a bit confusing, I think.

Generally, the term used for `=>` is "goes to" but some people say "maps to" or (in the case of lambdas that are used as predicates) "such that".

My personal preference is "maps to" (as suggested in the very first reply to the OP!).

Comment: +1 for "such that", and a generally thorough answer. As you mentioned, since I mainly use lambdas in predicates, "such that" makes a lot of sense, but other situations not so much.

Answer (score 5):

How about 'a returns b plus c'?

Answer (score 3):

Take this example:

```
var person = GetRandomPerson();

string firstname = person.Select(a => a.FirstName);
```

I understand that it's syntactically difficult. But in this case, `a` is the `person` variable. Since you can choose that name freely in a lambda expression, it becomes easier to understand like this:

```
string firstname = person.Select(person => person.FirstName);
```

**Keep in mind that there is no link between the `person` variable and the `person` lambda declaration** (whatever it's called) **. You can choose completely different names if you so choose.**

The `a` or `person` part before the `=>` is basically a declaration.

If you want it in words (like you asked): `a => a.FirstName` equates to "*if my item were called 'a', then please give me the FirstName of 'a'*"

This is what happens in a singular situation (i.e. there was only one person to select a field from).

Now what happens if you are holding a list of persons?

```
var persons = GetRandomPersons();

List<string> firstnames = persons.Select(a => a.FirstName);
```

If your base item (`persons`) is a collection of items, the `a` points toward each single object.

To make it more understandable:

```
List<string> firstnames = persons.Select(aSinglePerson => aSinglePerson.FirstName);
```

This code returns each person's FirstName. Assuming it's a `string`, this means that an `IEnumerable<string>` will be returned.

Think of it like doing the same with a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var aSinglePerson in persons)
{
    var firstname = aSinglePerson.FirstName;

    ...
```

If you want it in words (like you asked): For multiple items, `a => a.FirstName` equates to "*In this collection, sequentially take each individual item, call it 'a', and please give me the FirstName of 'a'*"

I hope this explains the concept behind a lambda expression in C# syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics `=>` symbol means [Implies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) but for some reason c# calls this as [Lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). It will not be easy to read as `a` Lambda operator`b` plus `c`

So you can simply call `a` implies `b` plus `c`

Answer (score 2):

I always think "goes to" myself.

Answer (score 2):

By definition in => is called lambda operator. Thy are used to separate inputs (on left) from the lambda body (on right). Your example do not stand for the same thing.

In your case more valid would be

`a = delegate() { b + c };`

that can be simplified using lambda to

`a = () => b + c;`

The lambda operator does not return anything, it more like "go to" or "use".